# Installing R library XLConnect on OS 10.8.2

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

[XLConnect](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/index.html) is, as the manual describes it, "a package that allows for reading, writing and manipulation of Microsoft Excel files from within R".

Installation on Windows and Linux is straightforward. Simply tell R to `install.packages("XLConnect")`, and you're done. On OS X you need to use `install.packages("XLConnect", type="source")`, the installation instructions say.

Trying this under OS 10.8.2, R output a number of error messages. I post them here, so Google can send people with similar problems to this Q and A. For a solution to the problem, scroll down.

---

R output:

```
> install.packages("XLConnect", type = "source")
also installing the dependencies ‘XLConnectJars’, ‘rJava’

versuche URL 'http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/misc/cran/src/contrib/XLConnectJars_0.2-4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 16539227 bytes (15.8 Mb)
URL geöffnet
==================================================
downloaded 15.8 Mb

versuche URL 'http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/misc/cran/src/contrib/rJava_0.9-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 537153 bytes (524 Kb)
URL geöffnet
==================================================
downloaded 524 Kb

versuche URL 'http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/misc/cran/src/contrib/XLConnect_0.2-4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1719698 bytes (1.6 Mb)
URL geöffnet
==================================================
downloaded 1.6 Mb

* installing *source* package ‘rJava’ ...
** Paket ‘rJava’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 142: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 143: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 219: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 142: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 143: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 219: make: command not found
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/rJava’
ERROR: dependency ‘rJava’ is not available for package ‘XLConnectJars’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/XLConnectJars’
ERROR: dependencies ‘XLConnectJars’, ‘rJava’ are not available for package ‘XLConnect’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/XLConnect’

Die heruntergeladenen Quellpakete sind in 
    ‘/private/var/folders/some/path/to/downloaded_packages’
Warnmeldungen:
1: In install.packages("XLConnect", type = "source") :
 Installation des Pakets ‘rJava’ hatte Exit-Status ungleich 0
2: In install.packages("XLConnect", type = "source") :
 Installation des Pakets ‘XLConnectJars’ hatte Exit-Status ungleich 0
3: In install.packages("XLConnect", type = "source") :
 Installation des Pakets ‘XLConnect’ hatte Exit-Status ungleich 0
> library(XLConnect)
Fehler in library(XLConnect) : es gibt kein Paket namens ‘XLConnect’
```

Answer (score 7):

Installation on Mac OSX is a tiny bit more complicated than the [installation instructions](http://miraisolutions.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/xlconnect-0-2-4/) suggest. Martin Studer at Mirai Solutions, the developer of the package, helped my solve my difficulties, and I want to post the procedure here to help other users possibly encountering the same problems.

1. **Install Java**
   Due to security concerns, recent versions of OS X come without Java. If you updated from a version with Java, it will have been uninstalled! [Check](http://www.java.com/en/download/index.jsp), if you have Java. If not, [download](http://www.java.com) and install it.
2. **Install rJava**
   You will (later) install XLConnect from source, because there is no binary for OS X. During this installation process, you will get an error, when R tries to install the dependent package rJava, because this must be installed from the binary. So you have to install it first, using
    `install.packages("rJava")`
3. **Install XLConnect**
   Finally, install XLConnect from source:
   `install.packages("XLConnect", type="source")`

Comment: And now you're free to discover all the other "quirks" about using XLConnect on a Mac. Sigh.

Comment: Ha ha, okay :-) At the moment it read my Excel Workbook fine and I'm manipulating my data, so I'm content.

Comment: Perhaps you'll have better luck than I, but just in case: be careful writing to an .xlsx file if your data frame have more than a few thousand rows. Bad things may happen.

Comment: Thank you for that warning, joran, I'll heed it.

Comment: I just tried this with a mac running OX 10.13.6 and it installed, but when I say "library( XLConnect )" it fails with the following error "error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so'"    It is failing to load XLConnectJars package.  Help?