# Creating objects from all .xlsx documents in working directory

Tags: r, for-loop, object

I am trying to create objects from all files in working directory with name of the original file. I tried to go the following way, but couldn't solve appearing problems.

```
# - SETTING WD
getwd()
setwd("PATH TO THE FILE")
library(readxl)

# - CREATING OBJECTS
file_objects <- list.files()
xlsx_objects <- unlist(grep(".xlsx",file_objects,value = T))

for (i in xlsx_objects) {
  xlsx_objects[i] <- read_xlsx(xlsx_objects[i], header = T)
}
```

I tried to `paste` [i]item from "xlsx_objects" with path to WD but it only created a list of files names from docs in WD.
I also find [information](https://statisticsglobe.com/r-error-in-file-invalid-description-argument), that `read.csv` can read only one file at the time, but I guess that it should be the case with for loop, right? It is reading only one file at the time.

Using `lapply` (as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273323/open-all-dataset-files-of-a-given-directory-in-r) forum) I was able to get the data in the environment, but argument `header` didn't work, I lost names of my docs in that object which does not have desired structure. I am though looking for having these files in separated objects without calling every document exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could do something like:

```
files = list.files("PATH TO THE FILE", full.names = T, pattern = 'xlsx')
list_files = map(files, readxl::read_excel)
```

(You can't use `read.csv` to read excel files)

Also I recommend reading about R Projects so you don't have to use `setwd()` ever again, which makes your code harder to reproduce down the pipeline